# How to create a multi-conditional 1D dataframe from a multi dimensional dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with scores for each product that needed to be sold for 10 days and availability of each product (totally number of products = 10)

```
A   B   C   D
20  56  12  65
80  13  76  51
24  81  56  90
67  12  65  87
45  23  67  50
62  32  23  75
76  34  67  67
23  45  32  98
24  67  34  12
56  53  32  78
```

Product availability

```
A   3
B   2
C   3
D   2
```

First I had to rank each product and prioritize what I need to sell for each day. I was able to do that by

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
num = len(list(df))
for i in range(1,num+1)  :
    new_df['Max'+str(i)] = df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(i).idxmin())

print(new_df)
```

That gives me

```
  Max1 Max2 Max3 Max4
0    D    B    A    C
1    A    C    D    B
2    D    B    C    A
3    D    A    C    B
4    C    D    A    B
5    D    A    B    C
6    A    C    C    B
7    D    B    C    A
8    B    C    A    D
9    D    A    B    C
```

now comes the hard part how do i create a table that contains the product to be sold for each day looking at the Max1 column but also keeping track of the availability. If the product is not available then chose the next maximum. The final df should look like this.

```
0   D
1   A
2   D
3   A
4   C
5   A
6   C
7   B
8   B
9   C
```

Breaking my head over this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('file1',sep='\s+',header=None,names=['product','available'])
print df1
df2=pd.read_csv('file2',sep='\s+')
print df2

maxy=[]
for i in range(len(df2)):
    if df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max1'][i]].values[0]>0:
        maxy.append(df2['Max1'][i])
        df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max1'][i]]=df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max1'][i]].values[0]-1
    elif df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max2'][i]].values[0]>0:
        maxy.append(df2['Max2'][i])
        df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max2'][i]]=df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max2'][i]].values[0]-1
    elif df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max3'][i]].values[0]>0:
        maxy.append(df2['Max3'][i])
        df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max3'][i]]=df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max3'][i]].values[0]-1
    elif df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max4'][i]].values[0]>0:
        maxy.append(df2['Max4'][i])
        df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max4'][i]]=df1['available'][df1['product']==df2['Max4'][i]].values[0]-1
    else:
        print ("Check")

pd.DataFrame(maxy)
```

Output:

```
 product  available
0       A          3
1       B          2
2       C          3
3       D          2
  Max1 Max2 Max3 Max4
0    D    B    A    C
1    A    C    D    B
2    D    B    C    A
3    D    A    C    B
4    C    D    A    B
5    D    A    B    C
6    A    C    C    B
7    D    B    C    A
8    B    C    A    D
9    D    A    B    C



    0
0   D
1   A
2   D
3   A
4   C
5   A
6   C
7   B
8   B
9   C
```

I was able to do that for any number of products through this

```
cols = list(df2)
maxy=[]

for i in range(len(df2)):
    for x in cols:
        if df1['available'][df1['product']==df2[x][i]].values[0]>0:
            maxy.append(df2[x][i])
            df1['available'][df1['product']==df2[x][i]]=df1['available'][df1['product']==df2[x][i]].values[0]-1
            break

final=pd.DataFrame(maxy)
print(final)
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try and figure out how to make this a function coz the number of products may change. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful given the number of products.

Comment: If you found this helpful and answered your problem, you want to check the green mark.